# How do I use transitionend in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I need to detect if a CSS transition is completed before allowing a function to repeat again, to prevent messing up the margins.

So how cam I have something like

```
if (transitionend == true) {
  // do stuff
} else {
  // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The code below will trigger on the transitionend event for whatever element(s) you have in the $element variable. There are four different event names as I believe these cover all of the cross-browser inconsistencies. Replace the '// your event handler' comment with whatever code you wish to run when the event is triggered.

```
$element.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function () {
    // your event handler
});
```

Comment: could you add an explanation to support your answer please

Comment: you should add some explanation too

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I have added an explanation.

Comment: This is the best answer in this thread because the original person was asking for **jQuery**. I'm saddened that people are complaining about "adding an explanation" the code itself is self-explanatory (assuming that you had initially just pasted the code)

Comment: +1 super happy to find this - didn't even realize these events existed

Comment: otransitionend is repeated. One of them should be mstransitionend to support IE.

Comment: @aperezroca Corrected the answer :)

Comment: Use `$element.one` instead of `$element.on` to prevent it from multiple execution

Comment: The only event you need to listen to now is the standard `transitionend`: It's supported in Chrome 36+, WebKit 7.0.6+, and Opera 12.10+. [IE still suffers a host of problems but you don't need the ms- prefix.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

Answer (score 8):

I think this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions) might be helpful to you.

> There is a single event that is fired when transitions complete. In
>   Firefox, the event is transitionend, in Opera, OTransitionEnd, and in
>   WebKit it is webkitTransitionEnd.

```
el.addEventListener("transitionend", updateTransition, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've seen that doc before and couldn't make heads or tails of it. I'm pretty new to javascript so adding event listeners and all that doesn't mean anything to me. I figured out a way of doing this on my own, but I plused on your answer for the effort :) Also posted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to attach stateful data to the element. Use a boolean value to "block" events from happening and flip the boolean variable once transitionend completes. Use xram's code to hook up all cross-browser transitionend events at the same time.

So for your example...

1. onclick set this.data('transitioning', true)
2. when transitionend fires, set this.data('transitioning', false)
3. don't perform animation if this.data('transitioning') == true. this is captured and checked in your click event.

Comment: This is really useful because xram's code may run multiple times

Comment: @Hengjie I don't think so, browsers either support the unprefixed version or the prefixed one.. never both.

Comment: Just tested in Google Chrome and got transitionend followed immediately by webkitTransitionEnd. I couldn't figure out why my end transition code was firing twice until I set an alert for event.type and saw it was firing for both events.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method which will keep in mind when the transition end has been called the last time, and thus only trigger the callback once.

```
function transitionEndsOnce($dom, callback) {
  var tick = Date.now();
  $dom.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function(e) {
    var diff = Date.now() - tick;
    tick = Date.now();
    if (diff > 20) { // this number can be changed, but normally all the event trigger are done in the same time
      return callback && callback(e);
    }
  });
}
```

and then simply use it this way

```
transitionEndsOnce($('...'), function(e){
  console.log('transition ends once');
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you unsubscribe the event using `off`?

Comment: If you want this to be called only once you need as you suggest to use off, but in this case you can use jQuery.one, which is doing the same. Here the idea was to merge all the transition ends for all properties in one single callback, maybe the method name should be change then ?

Comment: This is wrong! What's the meaning of runs once? "runs once between a bunch of nodes that produce the same event after an animation" or "runs once for the lifetime of an element"? In either case this code fails...

Answer (score 1):

I noticed such similar questions like **"how do I catch touchend events?"** or **"mouseup events?"** etc.

They are all similar for these points of view

1. **plural**: handlers are fired many times even when we are expecting to be fired by a single event
2. **depth**: events are bubbling deeper in the tree before our handler catches them.

Examples:

1. a `touchstart` can be followed by a `mousedown` and vice versa in a device that has both a mouse and a touch screen,
2. a `touchend` can be followed by a `mouseup` for the similar reasons,
3. a `animationstart` can be followed by many other similar events depending on how you wrote the css,
4. a `animationend` can also be followed by many similar events for the above reasons as well.

If we need to fire our handler **once** per a set of **similar** events, i.e. events that produced by a single action like a person that presses sth. we need to introduce an **event lock** and use 2 handlers one at the beginning of an event and one handler at the end **even if we don't need or want a handler of the side event**.

The **lock** can be a property at the parent node higer in the tree as you guessed.

For the infamous event couple: `animationstart` - `animationend` such a function can be:

```
var oneTransition = (function(){
   var $parent,
       type,
       callback,
       unlockCallback,
       newCallback,
       start = 'webkitTransitionStart otransitionstart oTransitionStart msTransitionStart transitionstart',
       end = 'webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend';

   unlockCallback = function(){
      $parent.data('oneTransitionLock', false);
   };

   newCallback = function(e){
      if($parent.data('oneTransitionLock'))
         return;
      else
         $parent.data('oneTransitionLock', true);

      callback(e);
   };

   return function(){
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

      $parent = $(args[0]);     // 1st arg
      type = args[1];           // 2nd arg
      callback = args[2];       // 3rd arg

      if((args.length < 3) || ((type != 'start') && (type != 'end')) || (typeof(callback) != 'function'))
         return;

      $parent.off(start).off(end);
      if(type == 'start'){
         $parent.data('oneTransitionLock', false);
         $parent.on(start, newCallback);
         $parent.on(end, unlockCallback);
      }else if(type == 'end'){
         $parent.on(start, unlockCallback);
         $parent.on(end, newCallback);
      }
   }
})();
```

and you can call it like:

```
oneTransition(node, 'start' or 'end', funcion(){...});
```

The interesting part is that it can runs for either the start or the end of animation:

1. 1st arg. a node reference,
2. 2nd arg. a string representing the event for our callback and
3. 3rd arg. our actual callback.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/centurianii/rqbznpke/)