# jQuery - Tell when CSS Animation hits 100%

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms, css-animations

Is there a way to tell when a animation hits 100% of its animation with jQuery?

```
{0%{-xxx-transform:translate(0,0);}
100%{-xxx-transform:translate(-500px, 300px); opacity: 0.1;}
```

Comment: You might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134584/how-do-i-use-transitionend-in-jquery it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right answer.

$(elem).bind('webkitAnimationEnd', function (event) {
        //function
    });

[How do I re-trigger a WebKit CSS animation via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797675/how-do-i-re-trigger-a-webkit-css-animation-via-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `transitionend` event.

```
$('#elem').bind('transitionend', function()
{
    alert('finished animating');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually transitionend wasn't the right way to go. But 'webkitAnimationEnd' or 'animationEnd'.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity's sake, here's a list of all the browser-specific 'animationEnd' properties:

```
$('#foo').bind('animationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd', function(event){
    // Do stuff once the CSS animation has finished.
});
```