# Getting done event on CSS Transition with AngularJS 1.2 and angular-animate

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Is it possible to get a done event of a CSS Transition with AngularJS 1.2 angular-animate module?

What I try to do is when I have a HTML Tag

```
<div ng-hide="{{toggle}}">...</div>
```

with a CSS - Transition like

```
.sidebar.ng-hide-add,
.sidebar.ng-hide-remove {
  transition:0.3s ease-out all;
  display:block!important;
}
```

and the corresponding `.ng-hide-add`, `.ng-hide-remove` (and active classes), that I call a function when the 0.3s transition is done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this solution - basically it works:
[How do I use transitionend in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134584/how-do-i-use-transitionend-in-jquery)

If someone wants to add a more angular-ish solution it would be great!