# addEventListener and FadeOut not working with TR

Tags: jquery, fadeout, addeventlistener

Ok, I've looked and looked and tried various other working solutions but am still stuck and I'm about to throw something.

I'm attempting to have a TR fade out and then hide after a link within a cell of said TR is clicked, with the below methods:

1 - jQuerys fadeOut / fadeTo (I've tried both)

```
  function delTrans(id){
    var name = "chkSelect" + id;
    var chk = document.getElementById(name);
    var tableRow = $(chk).closest('tr');
    tableRow.addClass("transition");
    $(tableRow).find("td").fadeTo('slow',0,function(){
      alert("finished");
    }); 
  }
```

This doesn't seem to do much at all, no js errors or warnings are generated, and there is no change to the output displayed on screen.

2 - addEventListener:

```
  function delTrans(id){
    var name = "chkSelect" + id;
    var chk = document.getElementById(name);
    element = $(chk).closest("tr");
    element.addClass("transition");
    element.addEventListener("transitionend", 
      function () {
        element.addClass("hidden"); 
      },
      true
    );
```

This only succeeds in generating a JS error of: Type Error. element.addEventListener is not a function. I have tried the addEventListener directly on the chk object and it is fine, implying that addEventListener wont work on the element 'tr'.

any suggestions welcomed

Comment: `addEventListener` would be applied to a DOM element but your `element` is a jQuery object. `element[0]` would be the underlying node. See here to use `.on()`: [How do I use transitionend in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134584/how-do-i-use-transitionend-in-jquery)

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks Alex, that gets me further by using element.on("transitionend", function()....);
however now its behaving much the same as via the fadeOut() method - nothing happens - the class "hidden" is not added nor does any fading occur :(

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need `transitionend`? There is a completion callback built in to fade: http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/fBzMB/

Comment: i was trying with jquery fadeOut and alternatively with css transition which required transitionend. I've actually resolved this now, the problem was with the placement of the transition statement in my css. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED. Problem was with neither fadeOout() OR addEventListener. The problem was with the CSS. unable to post as I no longer have a copy of what it was prior to fixing the issue