# Explanation of jQuery transitionend to stop CSS animation being interrupted

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

The closest thread I could find was [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134584/how-do-i-use-transitionend-in-jquery) however I'm having trouble implementing this.

**The setup (ideas welcome)**

I've made a jQuery slider - this particular slider will have several slider instances on a single page, as well as an undetermined number of children within each slider ('cards' that present 4 visible cards per "slide")  - as such the code I've implemented compares offset of the container itself, number of children, and uses CSS transition on the inner containing card container to slide across by the aformentioned offset amount while ensuring it doesn't go overboard.

This is a prototype so I've got a few alternate versions for the people I work with to look over, but I'm more interested in the "button" variety I've made.

**What I've got working**

- Multiple sliders on a single page
- Correct detection of how many "cards" are in a container
- Sliding across by the correct amount based of containers offset
- Dynamically determining beginning and end values to ensure there's no "overshooting" as it slides

**The issue**

Currently the user can "spam click" a button, interrupting the present css transition (500ms) prematurely starting a *new* CSS3 transition, causing the slider to be completely out of position :(

**Potential solution**

It seems as though the jQuery ***[transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend)*** property is what I'm after (the ability to detect when a CSS transition has completed in jQuery) however I'm completely unsure of implementation!

There's a lot of jargon terms in explanations that I would like to learn - however it seems as though they cyclically point to more jargon documentation or truncated forum replies. Just wondering if someone could assist in explaining what I'm doing wrong, and the principle of why.

**Caveats**

I fully expect to be admonished, called foolish etc - I am mostly a self-taught coder - fully self-taught in jQuery. I come from a background in Graphic Design (Hiss! Scowl!) and half a degree in Computer Science. Politeness and simple explanations (with accompanying links to appropriate manual spots) is always appreciated! While the full code is below, my particular point of confusion as mentioned is "transitionend" which I am attempting to use in the following manner:

```
$(cardsToShift).on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function () {
        cardsToShift.css("margin-left",margin);
    });
```

Where cards to shift is the container of all cards I shift L/R by the "margin" variable I've pre-calculated.

My logic behind this snippet above is *"this container won't shift while a transition is happening as I've wrapped it in the transitionend line, and - with no transition happening - it should execute the inner code. However if transition **is** happening, that code wont execute at all and the user will need to click again"*. (note, may have some slight syntax issues littered, can easily clean them up, but I've been cut and pasting like a mad thing - would just like that snippet explained mostly).

Thank you in advance (currently logging out for a bit, but will reply and provide further information as soon as I can).

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="card-container" id="fixed-long">
            <div class="card-set-buttons">
                <div class="card">card 1</div>
                <div class="card">card 2</div>
                <div class="card">card 3</div>
                <div class="card">card 4</div>
                <div class="card">card 5</div>
                <div class="card">card 6</div>
                <div class="card">card 7</div>
                <div class="card">card 8</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- As we have multiple sliders, I've opted for functions to be fully dynamic that work based off
    which one the user is interacting with. The caveat to this is that there are "levels" of nesting that
    need to be adhered to - you will notice you can set whatever class names you like in the jQuery "scripts.js" file-->
    <div class="section alt">
        <div class="nav-container"> 
            <div class="set-button left" id="left-one"></div><!--LEVEL 1: The buttons must not be put in the same level as the container for cards-->
            <div class="card-container" id="long-buttons"><!--LEVEL 2: this level needs a unique ID based on which slider is selected. This is the "viewport" or "tableau" that displays current sets of cards and serves to hide the rest-->
                <div class="card-set-buttons"><!--LEVEL 3: necessary div class which is the "long" container holding all the cards, name what you want-->
                    <div class="card">card 1</div><!--LEVEL 4: Nothing but cards at this level, name whatever class you like-->
                    <div class="card">card 2</div>
                    <div class="card">card 3</div>
                    <div class="card">card 4</div>
                    <div class="card">card 5</div>
                    <div class="card">card 6</div>
                    <div class="card">card 7</div>
                    <div class="card">card 8</div>
                    <div class="card">card 9</div>
                    <div class="card">card 10</div>
                    <div class="card">card 11</div>
                    <div class="card">card 12</div>
                    <div class="card">card 13</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="set-button right" id="right-one"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="card-container short" id="fixed-short">
            <div class="card-set-buttons">
                <div class="card">card 1</div>
                <div class="card">card 2</div>
                <div class="card">card 3</div>
                <div class="card">card 4</div>
                <div class="card">card 5</div>
                <div class="card">card 6</div>
                <div class="card">card 7</div>
                <div class="card">card 8</div>
                <div class="card">card 9</div>
                <div class="card">card 10</div>
                <div class="card">card 11</div>
                <div class="card">card 12</div>
                <div class="card">card 13</div>
                <div class="card">card 14</div>
                <div class="card">card 15</div>
                <div class="card">card 16</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section alt">
        <div class="nav-container four"> 
            <div class="set-button left" id="left-two"></div>
            <div class="card-container short" id="short-buttons">
                <div class="card-set-buttons">
                    <div class="card">card 1</div>
                    <div class="card">card 2</div>
                    <div class="card">card 3</div>
                    <div class="card">card 4</div>
                    <div class="card">card 5</div>
                    <div class="card">card 6</div>
                    <div class="card">card 7</div>
                    <div class="card">card 8</div>
                    <div class="card">card 9</div>
                    <div class="card">card 10</div>
                    <div class="card">card 11</div>
                    <div class="card">card 12</div>
                    <div class="card">card 13</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="set-button right" id="right-two"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="card-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
/*=========== BODY ============*/
body
{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.section {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.alt
{
    background:#f0f0f0; 
}

.section:nth-child(4)
{
    height: 1000px;
}

/*============ SHARED LAYOUT ===========*/
.card
{
    background:#B3E9FA;
    height: 350px;
    width: 250px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 0;
}

.card-container
{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 125px auto 0 auto;
    height: 350px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

/*=========== LONG FORMAT ===========*/

.card-container#fixed-long
{
    overflow-x:scroll;
}

.card-container .card:last-child
{
    margin-right: 0;
}

/*============ SQUARE FORMAT =================*/

.nav-container.four
{
    width: 650px;
}
.card-container.short
{
    height: 740px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.card-container#fixed-short
{
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
.card-container#short-buttons
{
    width: 530px;
}
.card-container#short-buttons .card,.card-container#fixed-short .card
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.card-container#short-buttons .card:last-child
{
    margin-right: 0;
}
.card-container.short .card-set-buttons
{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.card-container.short .card:nth-child(4n+1),.card-container.short .card:nth-child(4n+2)
{
    order: 1;
}
.card-container.short .card:nth-child(4n+4),.card-container.short .card:nth-child(4n+3)
{
    order: 2;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

/*============= SHARED BUTTON NAV ============*/

.card-set-buttons
{
    width: 3000px;
}

.set-button
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 40px;
    background:#791719;
}

.nav-container
{
    width: 1200px;
    margin:125px auto 0 auto;
}
.nav-container .card-container
{
    margin: 0;
    width: 1100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.set-button
{
    display:inline-block;
    z-index: 3;
}
.card-set-buttons
{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; /* Safari */
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
// JavaScript Document

/*===================== VARIABLES =======================*/

/*this is the class used as the "viewing glass" or "tableau" for the cards*/
var cardContainerClass = ".card-container";

/*class used for the card*/
var cardClass = ".card";

/*class used for the left nav*/
var navLeft = ".set-button.left";

/*class used for the right nav*/
var navRight = ".set-button.right";

/*how many cards to scroll by (serves as a "minimum" that doesn't change)*/
var scrollAmount = 4;

/*This set amount let's us know what offset to test against to see if a card is in position 1 or not*/
var positionOneOffsetX;
var positionOneOffsetY;

/*to keep track of toal number of cards (serves as a "maximum" that doesn't change) set on document load*/
var numOfCards;

/*numeral position of next card*/
var nextCardNum;

/*currentCard is the "position 1" card OBJECT. We must use relative cards to shift other cards for consistency*/
var currentCard;

/*numeral position of card in 1st place*/
var currentCardNum = 0;

/*scroll length amount*/
var shiftValue;

/*since we need to know what slider we are dealing with - we store the object we are managing in here*/
var container;


/*================= FUNCTIONS ===================*/

function calculateCards(containerId)
{
    /*As we have many sliders on the same page -
    We will need to dynamically calculate what we are dealing with every time
    we use the button clicked to find it's container's ID (done previously on button click function)
    after this, we see which card child is in first spot and set it as current*/

    /*get container we are dealing with*/
    var container = "#"+containerId;

    /*set the container's 1st position spot based off the container itself*/
    positionOneOffsetX = $(container).offset().left;
    positionOneOffsetY = $(container).offset().top;

    console.log("containers first child offset is: "+positionOneOffsetX+" "+positionOneOffsetY );
    console.log("containers offset is: "+$(container).offset().left+" "+$(container).offset().top);


    $(container+" "+cardClass).each(function(){

        /*test if the card position matches the 1st spot, if so - set as "current" card*/
        if(($(this).offset().left === positionOneOffsetX) && ($(this).offset().left === positionOneOffsetX)){

            currentCardNum = $(this).index()+1;
            currentCard = $(this);

        }   
    });

    numOfCards = $(container+" "+cardClass).length;
}

function nextCards(containerId)
{
    /*get container we are dealing with*/
    var container = "#"+containerId;

    /*set the number of the next card to load*/
    nextCardNum = currentCardNum + scrollAmount;

    adjustButtons(containerId);

    console.log("next card: "+nextCardNum);

    /*set the nextCard Object of the upcoming set*/
    var nextCard = $(container+" "+cardClass+":nth-child("+(nextCardNum)+")");

    /*get pixel value to shift by*/
    shiftValue = currentCard.offset().left - nextCard.offset().left;

    /*make the shift*/
    shiftCards(containerId);
}

function prevCards(containerId)
{   
    /*get container we are dealing with*/
    var container = "#"+containerId;

    /*set the number of the next card to load*/
    nextCardNum = currentCardNum - scrollAmount;

    console.log("next card = "+nextCardNum);

    adjustButtons(containerId);

    /*set the nextCard Object of the upcoming set*/
    var nextCard = $(container+" "+cardClass+":nth-child("+(nextCardNum)+")");

    /*get pixel value to shift by*/
    shiftValue = currentCard.offset().left - nextCard.offset().left;

    /*make the shift*/
    shiftCards(containerId);
}

function shiftCards(containerId)
{
    /*get the container we are moving*/
    var container = $("#"+containerId);

    console.log("#"+containerId);
    /*select the container's direct div child to shift*/
    var cardsToShift = container.children("div");

    /*we will shift with margin-left value. Do some math to add or subtract our change*/
    var margin = parseInt(cardsToShift.css("margin-left"));

    if(margin > $(container).offset().left){
        margin = $(container).offset().left + cardsToShift.offset().left;
        currentCard = 1;
    }
    margin = margin + shiftValue;

    $(cardsToShift).on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function () {
        cardsToShift.css("margin-left",margin);
    });
}

function adjustButtons(containerId)
{
    /*get the container we are moving*/
    var container = $("#"+containerId);
    var leftButton = $(container).siblings(navLeft);
    var rightButton = $(container).siblings(navRight);

    /*adjust nav buttons for various circumstances to appear as unselectable*/
    if(numOfCards < scrollAmount)
    {
        /*less cards than size of "viewport"*/
        rightButton.css("opacity","0.5");
        leftButton.css("opacity","0.5");

    } else if(nextCardNum > (numOfCards - scrollAmount + 1)){

        /*max reached but room on left - set next card to the total cards minus our scroll amount*/
        nextCardNum = $("#"+containerId+" "+cardClass).length;

        console.log("max reach: "+nextCardNum);
        rightButton.css("opacity","0.5");

    } else if((nextCardNum <= 1)&&(numOfCards > scrollAmount)){

        /*min reached but room on right - set next card to the total cards minus our scroll amount*/
        nextCardNum = 1;
        leftButton.css("opacity","0.5");

    } else {

        /*room either side - set all buttons to clickable*/
        leftButton.css("opacity","1");
        rightButton.css("opacity","1");
    }
}

function setWidth(cardContainerClass)
{
    /*adds up all cards, sets width of container to be their total*/

    var container;

    $(cardContainerClass).each(function() {
        console.log("container here");
        container = $(this).prop("id");

        /*set total number of cards*/
        numOfCards = $("#"+container+" "+cardClass).length;

        var containerWidth = 0;

        $("#"+container+" "+cardClass).each(function(){
            containerWidth += parseInt($(this).width());
            containerWidth += parseInt($(this).css("margin-right"));
            containerWidth += 4;
        }); 

        /*set width of container based on cards calculated for this slider*/
        if ($("#"+container).hasClass("short")){
            /*short form*/
            containerWidth = containerWidth/2+100;
            $("#"+container+" .card-set-buttons").css("width",containerWidth+"px");

        } else {
            /*long form*/
            $("#"+container+" .card-set-buttons").css("width",containerWidth+"px");     }

    });

}


function navCall(button)
{
    /*set which slider we are using by it's ID */
    container = $(button).siblings(cardContainerClass).prop("id");  

    console.log("container "+container);

    /*set some variables based on the unique container ID interacted with*/
    calculateCards(container);

    if (numOfCards > 1)
    {
        if($(button).hasClass("left"))
        {
            prevCards(container);       
        } else {
            nextCards(container);
        }

    }

}


/*==================== CALLS =====================*/

$(document).ready(function() {

    /*disable left scroll on load*/
    $(cardContainerClass).siblings(navLeft).css("opacity","0.5");

    /*set width of all sliders based on cards in each one. Works for short and long form*/
    setWidth(cardContainerClass);

    $(navLeft).click(function(){
        navCall($(this));
    });

    $(navRight).click(function(){
        navCall($(this));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay - well after a nice sleep and some coffee I have an answer for this one (as usual more logical and easy than expected):

So *transitionend* **fires** once a transition is complete on something that is transitioning - so I have opted to set a class which is used as a "test" that I can look for - if the class is there, I don't proceed with further transitions, if it isn't there though, I proceed as normal.

In this case - I can apply a CSS class... Well to anything really - however the important part is that I use *transitionend* **on the transitioning CSS class** and in that *transitionend* call I remove the class I set earlier - so my "disable" class is only removed upon transition completion, and the transition can only run *without* the class:

```
/*MOVE - note "cardsToShift" has CSS transition applied to it*/
cardsToShift.css("margin-left",margin); 

/*add class - while added no more moving will happen*/
$(container).addClass("disabled");

/*end of transition - removed disabled */
$(cardsToShift).one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {

$(container).removeClass("disabled");
```

This is where the magic happens - you should be able to gauge from my original code where abouts this takes place (in my shiftCards() function)

The check for 'disabled class' then acts as a 'gate keeper' up the chain thus:

```
/*check for the class as a gate keeper!!! The class can only be removed upon transition completion*/
if($("#"+container).hasClass("disabled"))
{
    /*do nothing*/
    console.log("DOUBLE FIRE!!!");
} else {
     /*else - no gatekeeper class - go ahead with transition etc.

    /*arbitrary to problem - check to make sure there's stuff to move*/
    if (numOfCards > 1)
    {
        /*arbitrary to problem, check if left or right button was clicked*/
        if($(button).hasClass("left"))
        {
            prevCards(container);       
        } else {
            nextCards(container);
        }
    }
}
```