# Trying to use transitionend event instead of setTimeout

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have this code:

```js
$("#disable").click(function () {
     $("body").append("<div id='blackDisable' class='fade'> </div>");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#blackDisable").addClass("showBack");
    }, 150);
});
```

```css
.fade {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .15s linear;
}
        
.showBack {
    opacity: .5;
}

#blackDisable {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2222;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button id="disable">Click Me</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I don't want to use `setTimeout` to force the transition work, so I searched for a solution and found `transitionend` event and replaced the `setTimeout` with `transitionend` event handler but it didn't fired.

How could I remove this `setTimeout` and use the `transitionend` event?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english!

Comment: I don't think that's what you're looking for. There is no `transition` event in your code that will end before you want to apply `$("#blackDisable").addClass("showBack")`. `.showBack` is the class with the transition - so you can't wait for that to end before applying it -
 make sense? `setTimeout` is the way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134584/how-do-i-use-transitionend-in-jquery

Comment: I know how to use it but it didn't worked @CBroe

Comment: So for example bootstrap modal works the same with `setTimeout`?@MichaelCoker

Comment: I don't think transitionend has anything to do with your problem. It's an *issue* of immediately assigning classes to newly created (not yet DOM-styles-discoverable)  elements - without a callback - where setTimeout acts actually like a DOM ready hack.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys it seems that `setTimeout` is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`transitionend` has anything to do with your problem - since there was no transition to register any *end*.
It's an issue of immediately assigning classes to newly created (not yet DOM-styles-discoverable) elements - **`without a callback`** - where `setTimeout` acts actually like a "DOM-ready *hack*".

Without `setTimeout`? Two ways (or even more):

### 1. `animation` (instead of `transition`)

```js
$("#disable").click(function() {

  $("body").append("<div id='blackDisable' class='fade'></div>");
  $("#blackDisable").addClass("showBack");
  
});
```

```css
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  /* no transition */
}

.showBack {
  /*opacity: .5; not ready, instead let the browser assign/trigger keyframes */
  animation : fadeIn 0.3s linear forwards;
}

#blackDisable {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2222;
  background-color: black;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to { opacity: 0.5; }
}
```

```html
<button id="disable">Click Me</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

### 2. Appending before any event

and using CSS `visibility` to prevent overlapping problems

```js
// Append on DOM ready
$("body").append("<div id='blackDisable' class='fade'></div>");

// CALLBACK
$("#disable").click(function() {
  // Since the callback, it's now discoverable,
  // DOM set, CSS styles are set and we can transition! 
  $("#blackDisable").addClass("showBack");

});
```

```css
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden; /* you need this!!!!!! */
  transition: opacity .3s linear;
}

.showBack {
  opacity: .5;
  visibility: visible; /* and this!!!!!! */
}

#blackDisable {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2222;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button id="disable">Click Me</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

### 3. queue

```js
$("#disable").click(function() {

  $("body").append("<div id='blackDisable' class='fade'></div>");
  
  // Instead of setTimeout but again mimicking a callback
  $("#blackDisable").delay().queue(function(){
    $(this).addClass("showBack");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s linear;
}

.showBack {
  opacity: .5;
}

#blackDisable {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2222;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button id="disable">Click Me</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I don't like the first way because the `blackDisable` will be on the DOM in the beginning. The second way looks good but I don't really understand how it works. What the `delay` and `queue` functions do?

Comment: @Sagie edited my answer, I'd use `animation` instead of `transition` - To answer your comment, `.queue()` (jQuery) is a way to defer events after binding animation to an element. `delay` is an animation, so actually acts like your `setTimeout` just in a more jQuer-ysh way.

Comment: I will stay with the `transition` way. In the jQuery documantion I saw that `delay()` gets duration time for delaying. How in your example it knows how much time to delay?