# Adding a class then removing it only when the animation is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container on the top of my page that is "hidden" using transform: translate(). When I click on an icon I want this container to slide down, pushing the whole page the the bottom. I've done this using CSS: transform: translate(). When I click I add few Css classes for the main containers of the page like the header, footer and the main section. This works.

Now I want this animation to be smooth. And now come my problems.. When I click to make the container visible, it should add the "transition" through a class to all the main containers then add the classes that make the "push to the bottom" (defined with translate(Y)). This also works.

But when the container is visible and I click one more time on the icon I want the container to slide up (still using translate) to its original position. That means that when the container is visible and I want to "close" it, it should remove the classes that define the translate(Y) and THEN remove the class that defines the transition.

So:
click -> transition -> translate(Y)
When open:
click -> translate(Y) -> transition

I tried to use the "bind" and "on" Methods in order to detect the end of the animation but this doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
$(".language-menu-action").click(function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass("show")) {
          $(".sticky-scroll-box").removeClass("header-show");
          $("#pageBody, .footer").removeClass("open-header");
          $(".language-menu-action").removeClass("show");

          $('.animated-transform').bind('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend     oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function (e) {
              $('#pageBody, .footer, .navbar').removeClass('animated-transform');
        });

      } else {
          $('#pageBody, .footer, .navbar').addClass('animated-transform');

          $(".sticky-scroll-box").addClass("header-show");
          $("#pageBody").addClass("open-header");
          $(".footer").addClass("open-header");
          $(".language-menu-action").addClass("show");
      }
  });
```

Update: I'm currently using a delay.

```
$(".language-menu-action").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("show")) {
        $(".sticky-scroll-box").removeClass("header-show");
        $("#pageBody, .footer").removeClass("open-header");
        $(".language-menu-action").removeClass("show");

        $('#pageBody, .footer, .navbar').delay(350).queue(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('animated-transform').dequeue();
        });

    } else {
        $('#pageBody, .footer, .navbar').addClass('animated-transform');

        $(".sticky-scroll-box").addClass("header-show");
        $("#pageBody").addClass("open-header");
        $(".footer").addClass("open-header");
        $(".language-menu-action").addClass("show");
    }
});
```

If there is any better solution I take it ;)

Comment: @TylerRoper I've seen that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134584/how-do-i-use-transitionend-in-jquery

Comment: @wpwa_pg Interesting! I wasn't aware. If you're to go that route, you'll likely not want to use `.bind` (it's ancient, and has since been replaced by `.on`), and you'll want your handler to be **outside** of the menu click, otherwise you'll be attaching a duplicate event each time you click the menu. Additionally,  your question should contain a [**minimal, complete, verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you could edit and add your relevant HTML, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @TylerRoper I try to do it in the next days ;)